# Let $V= \mathbb{R}^n$. If $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and dim$U$ $\leq n-2$ then there are infinitely many subspaces $X$ such that $U \leq X \leq V$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

For 3(c) my proof is:

Let $v_1,v_2 \in V$ be linearly independent vectors with $v_1,v_2 \notin U$.  Let $X_{c}=U+span(cv_1+v_2)$ for some scalar $c$.  Clearly $U \leq X \leq V$.  Since there are infinitely many choices for $c$ there are infinitely many such $X_{c}$.  Moreover, for $c' \neq c$, if $c'v_1+v_2 \in X_c$ then $c'v_1+v_2=u+cv_1+v_2$ for some $u \in U$.  So $v_1=u/(c'-c) \in U$ contradicting that $v_1\notin U$.  Hence $c'v_1+v_2 \notin X_c$ and $X_c \neq X_c'$, that is, each $X_c$ is distinct.

Is this proof okay?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is OK. The only little hole in your proof is that you don't explain why $v_1$ and $v_2$ exist. But that's easily done :
Since $\dim(U) = n-2$, there's a basis of $U$ of length $n-2$, say $(x_1, \dots, x_{n-2})$. By the incomplete basis theorem, you can complete the linearly independent family $(x_1, \dots, x_{n-2})$ into a basis of $V$, say $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$. Now you can take $v_1 := x_{n-1}$ and $v_2 := x_n$.